# This dictionary where the value is a Set doesn't seem to load in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, memory, set

I mapped all adjacent keys for every key on a keyboard, so that I can quickly look up a key (e.g. "a") and check if a key is adjacent or not to a in constant time.

It's hard for me to believe that this is that memory intensive, but if I only have the keys a-k it loads, but after a while, everytime I add a key, the time goes up dramatically, with all keys it doesn't load at all and is stuck on "compiling swift source files"

```
var adjcacencyCharacters = [
    "a": Set(["a", "q", "w", "s", "z"]),
    "b": Set(["b", "v", "g", "h", "n", "j", " "]),
    "c": Set(["c", "x", "d", "f", "v", "g", " "]),
    "d": Set(["d", "s", "e", "r", "f", "c", "x", "z"]),
    "e": Set(["e", "w", "s", "d", "r"]),
    "f": Set(["f", "d", "r", "t", "g", "v", "c", "x"]),
    "g": Set(["g", "f", "t", "y", "h", "b", "v", "c"]),
    "h": Set(["h", "g", "y", "u", "j", "v", "n", "b"]),
    "i": Set(["i", "u", "j", "k", "o"]),
    "j": Set(["j", "b", "u", "i", "k", "m", "n", "h"]),
    "k": Set(["k", "j", "i", "o", "l", "m", "n"]),
    "l": Set(["l", "k", "o", "p", "m"]),
    "m": Set(["m", "j", "k", "l", "n"]),
    "n": Set(["n", "b", "h", "j", "k", "m", " "]),
    "o": Set(["o", "i", "k", "l", "p"]),
    "p": Set(["p", "o", "l"]),
    "q": Set(["q", "w", "a"]),
    "r": Set(["r", "e", "d", "f", "t"]),
    "s": Set(["s", "a", "w", "e", "d", "z"]),
    "t": Set(["t", "r", "f", "g", "y"]),
    "u": Set(["u", "y", "h", "j", "i"]),
    "v": Set(["v", "c", "f", "g", "b", "h", " "]),
    "w": Set(["w", "q", "a", "s", "e"]),
    "x": Set(["x", "z", "s", "d", "f", "c"]),
    "y": Set(["y", "t", "g", "h", "u"]),
    "z": Set(["z", "a", "s", "d", "x"])
]
```

Comment: Update: After about 15-20 minutes it compiled, and ran the app. I wonder why this takes so long. Try it in playground, something must be wrong. Is there a way to make this faster, while maintaining a set for each key value for constant lookup time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look like an edge case in Swift's type inference system. You can help it by explicitly specifying the type:

```
var adjcacencyCharacters: [String: Set<String>] = [
    ...
]
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I did just the same thing and it compiled nearly instantly after I saved the playground, quit Xcode, and re-opened the playground.

Comment: Good note indeed.